# Swing - Scrollable Grid

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing code for a server where when each client connects, their username is displayed by adding a `JLabel` onto the server's GUI dynamically, e.g.:

```
public class Server {

    public void connect () {
        //Handle client
        frame.add(new JLabel(client.getUsername()));
    }

}
```

Now I'd like to add these onto a grid/table with three columns, with each `JLabel` occupying a different cell. When the table is filled, the table should become scrollable as more rows are added automatically.

I'm not sure how to do this. Adding a `GridLayout` and a `JScrollPane` to the same `JFrame` sets the `JScrollPane` to one cell, rather than the whole table.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), 
[How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), 
[How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid has to be **inside the scroll pane**. This can be achieved by using the constructor

```
JScrollPane(Component view)
```

or

```
JScrollPane(Component view, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)
```

You can also adjust the scroll pane so that the scroll bars ar hidden when they aren't needed:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(myGrid,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Afterwards, you have to add the scroll pane to the iframe, but not the grid.

Comment: What exactly would `Component view` be? I'm guessing a `JFrame` with a `GridLayout`?

Comment: Swing components are **inside a JFrame**, for example JPanel, JLabel, JScrollPane, etc.